# Mysql DIsk Read Operations for each query

Tags: mysql

For Each Mysql Query how many Disk Read Operations would be performed , whether it will depend on the No of Rows in the Table . I would like to know the No of Operations on a Disk for a mysql query. 
Can any one please shed light on this

Comment: Why don't you use Mysql query browser and get the statistics of the query run ... which will show you the info you need.

Comment: `show status like '%read%';`

If is innodb :- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_rows_read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For INNODB table you can track number of read blocks

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
```

look for the variable "Key_reads".

thanks to @ajreal

Answer (score 1):

Mani, You can try explain before your query explain(SELECT * FROM ***) which will give you the number of rows the query searches to give the response.